Thevenin Impedance of a Circuit with Multiple Dependant and Independant Sources
I am attempting to find the Thevenin impedance or the output impedance of the circuit shown in the following image. I have tried simplifying the circuit into two parallel impedances, one of which is just a capacitance. The rest of the circuit, however, has four sources: two independent voltage sources and two dependent current-controlled voltage sources. The circuit is redrawn to simplify the structure. How could I further go about trying to simplify the circuit so I can use superposition to solve this? Could there be a simpler way of solving this circuit besides superposition?


I don't understand some of your terms/factors.

I am not sure what terms you are talking about. The circuit is represented in the Laplace domain, with s representing the Laplace variable. x, y, and P are constant, and so are Vd and Vq. The only variable quantities are the currents id and iq.

Honestly, the circuit data lead to misunderstandings. To avoid this, I limited myself to describing the circuit in my own way. However, we arrive at an equation with two unknowns, as you can see below, so we cannot continue:


Thank you for your response. This is something I was struggling with as well. I will take another look at this at the end of this week, maybe.

Strange (artificial?) problem.
Voc should be calculable by writing KVL around the loop in the lower diagram. Then apply a test voltage source and solve for It, Z = Vt/It.

The problem is certainly not artificial and relates to the open-loop output impedance calculation of a three-phase voltage source converter. I understand your approach, but I am having trouble trying to simplify the circuit for superposition in each case.
